# Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 with JRE 7 not starting

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

I am running a **virtual server** in the web on **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS / 32 Bit**.
After a clean install of **JRE 7** and **Tomcat 7**, following the instructions on http://www.sysadminslife.com, I don't get Tomcat 7 up and running.

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
> /etc/init.d/tomcat start
Starting Tomcat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
> telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

netstat sometimes shows a Java process, most of the times not. If it does, nothing works either.

**Does anyone have a solution or encountered similar situations?**
Here are the contents of **catalina.out**:

```
16.11.2012 18:36:39 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
16.11.2012 18:36:40 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
16.11.2012 18:36:40 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
16.11.2012 18:36:40 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1509 ms
16.11.2012 18:36:40 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
16.11.2012 18:36:40 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
16.11.2012 18:36:40 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager
```

Here come the results of **ps -ef**, **iptables --list** and **netstat -plut**:

```
> ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 init
root         2     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd/206616]
root         3     2  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 [khelper/2066167]
root         4     2  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 [rpciod/2066167/]
root         5     2  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 [rpciod/2066167/]
root         6     2  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 [rpciod/2066167/]
root         7     2  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 [rpciod/2066167/]
root         8     2  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 [nfsiod/2066167]
root       119     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       125     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       157   125  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       158   125  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       205     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root       276     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root       335     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/xinetd -dontfork -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid -stayalive -inetd
root       348     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 cron
syslog     368     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/syslogd -u syslog
root       472     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master
postfix    482   472  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
root       520     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   523   520  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   525   520  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   526   520  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
tomcat    1074     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:01:08 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/
postfix   1351   472  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u -c
postfix   3413   472  0 17:00 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u -c
root      3457   276  0 17:31 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/0
root      3459  3457  0 17:31 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
root      3470  3459  0 17:31 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef

> iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8005
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

> netstat -plut
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN      472/master
tcp        0      0 *:3213                  *:*                     LISTEN      276/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:smtp               [::]:*                  LISTEN      472/master
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8009               [::]:*                  LISTEN      1074/java
tcp6       0      0 [::]:3213               [::]:*                  LISTEN      276/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http-alt           [::]:*                  LISTEN      1074/java
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN      520/apache2
```

Comment: It seems to have to do with the virtualization software of my host provider: strato. To be verified.

Comment: Hello again @AndreasKrueger. As you probably can tell, it all looks healthy. I've just read those blog posts and one is about adding a `org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve` to restrict access. Can you post this section of server.xml?

Comment: Hi @Fuzzyfelt. Thanks for your continuous support. But I am pretty sure now that it has nothing to do with the software, but with the operating system itself. My provider strato.de seems to have general issues with Java on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. (As I did not report, at times I had Java VM errors logged in catalina.out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **installation** above was **correct**, thanks @Fuzzyfelt for the verification.

After many unsuccessful tries and attempts with other Java version, I gave up and searched the web (again) for hints. Finally, I came across this post

http://orange-coding.net/2012/08/10/strato-vserver-ubunut-12-04java/

**Strato (strato.de) have errors in their virtualization software running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Java.**

Switching today to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and everyhting's fine!

I will leave this post here, unless someone gives me a reasonable argument to delete it. There should be more resources in the web pointing out that problem with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Java on Strato, as far as I am concerned.